# Convert HTML table to Array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, html-table

I would like to convert a HTML table to an array. Where every line of the table is a new object.

Here an example of how the array should look like

```
var aSP2010Feature = [{
    DisplayName: "AccSrvMSysAso",
    Title: "Access Services System Objects",
    ID: "29ea7495-fca1-41c6-8ac1-500c247a036e",
    Scope: "Web",
    Description: blablabla
},
{
    DisplayName: "AccSrvRestrictedList",
    Title: "Access Services Restricted List Definition",
    ID: "a4d4ee2c-a6cb-4591-ab0a-21bb5bde92fb",
    Scope: "Web",
    Description: blablabla
},
{
    DisplayName: "AccSrvShell",
    Title: "No Title",
    ID: "bcf89eb7-bca1-4589-bdb4-ca27f61a2292",
    Scope: "Web",
    Description: blablabla
}];
```

Here I have an example of my table. The original table has more than 300 rows.

```
<table border='1'><tr><th>Display Name</th><th>Title</th><th>Scope</th><th>ID</th><th>Description</th></tr>

<tr><td>XmlFormLibrary</td><td>XML Form Libraries</td><td>Web</td><td>00bfea71-1e1d-4562-b56a-f05371bb0115</td><td>Provides support for XML form libraries for a site.</td></tr>
<tr><td>LinksList</td><td>Links Lists</td><td>Web</td><td>00bfea71-2062-426c-90bf-714c59600103</td><td>Provides support for links lists for a site.</td></tr>
<tr><td>workflowProcessList</td><td>WorkflowProcessList Feature</td><td>Web</td><td>00bfea71-2d77-4a75-9fca-76516689e21a</td><td>This feature provides the ability to create a list to support running custom form actions.
</td></tr>
</table>
```

```js
var tdCollection = $("table").find("td");
var array = [];
$.each(tdCollection, function(key, el){    
     array.push($(el).text());     
});
console.log(array);
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Text</th>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Notification Time</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Lab1</td>
<td>Some Text</td>
<td>Day of Week</td>
<td>Monday, Wednessday</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Lab2</td>
<td>Some Text</td>
<td>Day of Week</td>
<td>Tuesday, Wednessday</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How about you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qqdwct7h/ 
This I tried already. But this does not put the "Display name", "Title" in front of every object

Comment: What you're trying to generate is an object array, so you should get keys to use in the key-value pairs (hint: `<th>` and `<td>` are the keys and values respectively)

Comment: That is actually a really good idea. Make a counter or something that will start with 1 and the first <td> it finds put "Display Name:" in front of it. After that the second <td> it finds put "Title" in front of it... I will post the out come :D

Comment: Actually, you could make that solution more "universal" by reading 1 `<tr>` at a time and leaving the `<th>`s in an array and then using them as keys based on the index of the `<td>` inside the `<tr>` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `call` methods like `Array#slice`, `Array#map`, and `Array#reduce` on the `table.rows` and `tr.cells` NodeLists to convert your table to a nested data structure. This method will support an arbitrary number of columns in your table.

### Demo Snippet

```js
var rows = [].slice.call($('table')[0].rows)

var keys = [].map.call(rows.shift().cells, function(e) {
  return e.textContent.replace(/\s/g, '')
})

var result = rows.map(function(row) {
  return [].reduce.call(row.cells, function(o, e, i) {
    o[keys[i]] = e.textContent
    return o
  }, {})
})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Display Name</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Scope</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>XmlFormLibrary</td>
    <td>XML Form Libraries</td>
    <td>Web</td>
    <td>00bfea71-1e1d-4562-b56a-f05371bb0115</td>
    <td>Provides support for XML form libraries for a site.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LinksList</td>
    <td>Links Lists</td>
    <td>Web</td>
    <td>00bfea71-2062-426c-90bf-714c59600103</td>
    <td>Provides support for links lists for a site.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>workflowProcessList</td>
    <td>WorkflowProcessList Feature</td>
    <td>Web</td>
    <td>00bfea71-2d77-4a75-9fca-76516689e21a</td>
    <td>This feature provides the ability to create a list to support running custom form actions.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not comfortable with Array# functions. There is a simple solution:

```
var tdCollection = $("table").find("tr");

var array = [];
    var temp = {
    DisplayName: "",
    Title: "",
    ID: "",
    Scope: "",
    Description: ""
    };
$.each(tdCollection, function(key, el){    
    var i=0;
    var row = $(el).find("td");
    for (var f in temp){
        temp[f] = $(row[i++]).text()
    }
    array.push(temp);   
});
console.log(array);
```